# How to fix the error 500, When I uploaded website to production

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js

How to fix the internal server error 500 or sometimes show Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error), When i uploaded Website to production, It is specific admin panel after logged in (frontend or Home page none log in, It's with a status of 200 ok ), But on localhost (Xampp) everything it's with a status of 200 ok
I configuration database is all right, Can register and saved user data to database

This is Controllers

```js
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Admin;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Resources\Admin\AbilityResource;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AbilitiesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $permissions = auth()->user()->roles()->with('permissions')->get()
            ->pluck('permissions')
            ->flatten()
            ->pluck('title')
            ->toArray();

        return new AbilityResource($permissions);
    }
}
```

[image: localhost it's with a status of 200 ok]

Comment: Usually, your application's error log contains more information. Check it, and attach the error to your question. Also, please share your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: A 500 server error can be a lot of things, take a look at your laravel.log file or the error log file on your server to find out whats wrong

Comment: on prod check your logs like storage/laravel.log or nginx/apacahe logs.  Sometimes servers set a max upload of 1mb by default.

Answer (score -2):

go to app.js and change 127.0.0.1 to your domain address ,
after run npm run watch and clear you cache

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. How could this resolve the given server error?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.